# Building Qt 4.8.3 on Windows and integrating it with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, qt

I've been trying to build Qt 4.8.3 and everything went fine with configuring it (using the `configure` command). But when I try to run `nmake`, I get the following error:

> Generating Code...
>           link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.8.3\lib" /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.8.3\lib" /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /BASE:0x67000000 /DEBUG /DLL /MANIFEST
>   /MANIFESTFILE:"tmp\obj\debug_shared\QtCored.int 83
>   /OUT:....\lib\QtCored4.dll @C:\Users\Maikati\AppData\Local\Temp\nm6CC4.tmp
>   Creating library ....\lib\QtCored4.lib and object
>   ....\lib\QtCored4.exp LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during
>   conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt NMAKE : fatal error U1077:
>   'D:\vs2010\VC\BIN\link.EXE' : return code '0x463'
>
> Stop. NMAKE : fatal
>   error U1077: 'D:\vs2010\VC\BIN\nmake.exe' : return code '0x2' Stop.
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2' Stop.

I've googled my error and there were almost no results with link.exe, so I decided to ask here. Any help will be appreciated ;)

Comment: May be it's easier to download already built version of qt?

Comment: @Ivan I don't know how to link it and stuff.

Comment: clean build and try with steps given here for 32 bit http://qtitkvtkhelp.blogspot.in/2012/11/qt-installation-prerequisite-1.html and for 64 bit http://qtitkvtkhelp.blogspot.in/2013/04/qt-64-bit-build.html HTH

Comment: @maikati I agree with Ivan, you should be able to download the pre-built version.  Typically you'd want to rebuild if you've made changes to code or want a static lib version.  My question though is, what do you mean by "integrating"?  Building Qt doesn't have anything to do with "linking" to it - the paths should be found in something like c:\Qt\.. so it's only a matter of setting up project dependencies if you don't use the Qt's MSVC add-in.